# Serve Django from root domain with Apache, and also use /var/www/html

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm new to Django and Apache, so apologies if my terminology is a bit off.

I have a Django app that I'm serving with Apache using mod_wsgi.  I used [this](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) guide, and just switched to Apache from the Django dev server.  In my 000-default.conf file I have this line

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/Projects/myapp/wsgi.py
```

Everything works fine and the homepage of my app is example.com. However, I find now that there are images (a few tilesets) that I was previously accessing at example.com/tiles which are now not accessible, because they are actually stored at /var/www/html/tiles.

I understand why the paths aren't working, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can keep running the django site from example.com while also serving the tiles from a different directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you add a preceding configuration directive:

```
Alias /tiles /var/www/html/tiles
```

... it should fix it.

Please note that order of Apache configuration directives may matter. [More information about Apache and Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.  I added that line in the 000-default.conf file, right before the lines that define the wsgi processing.

Comment: And is covered in mod_wsgi documentation at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting_Of_Static_Files For an alternate approach which allows interleaving of files in DocumentRoot and your application, see towards end of section http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive